# Not able to add bootstrap to Angular Project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add bootstrap to my angular project but I am not able to. I am not getting any errors either.

I even tried some of the solutions on stackoverflow. I am using Angular 7. I have installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.js. I have also added them to angular.json.

Below is my **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"],
```

Following is my import statement in **AppModule.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from 'bootstrap';
```

I havent included it in the imports array. Because when I did I got the following error

```
Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that one of the NgModules that you're trying to import into AppModule is not defined.  Did you "export" the NgModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
```

Maybe you exceeded another *dot* for `popper.js`.
Check also your node_modules if the paths are correct.

Comment: also, if you edited angular.json, try building and running again

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to import bootstrap in your **AppModule.ts** file, You can use bootstrap classes without import any module. Because you already imported **bootstrap css and js** files in your **angular.json** file